# Using Extract while returning a value from a generic

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to return a value by extracting its type from an union type of objects.

I've been able to get it work using `keyof` with a mapped key -> object, however I would prefer using a union type.

Considering the following example:

```js
type List = { name: "Hello" } | { name: "Hi!" }

export function returnTheSameName<K extends List["name"]>(name: K): Extract<List, { name: K }>["name"] {
  return name
}
```

I get a TS2322 error, it looks like TypeScript faces difficulties at understanding that the returned type is actually the same as K. Why?

My objective is then to be able to return `Extract<List, { name: K }>` so I can, from a string type in the union, find the whole object the key belongs to.

Comment: Why dont you just enumerate `name` of type List, and then use as argument

Comment: Well, by writing `K extends List["name"]`, K is a union type of all the possible values for name. I guess this is what you mean by enumerate? Also I need K because it is used to precise the exact return type of the function.

Comment: TypeScript's compiler doesn't do much analysis on conditional types (like `Extract`) which depend on unresolved generic parameters (like `K`). For the example above, I'd say just annotate the return type as `K`.  If that doesn't work for you, could you explain your use case and provide a corresponding [mcve]?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple function with conditional type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52144772/simple-function-with-conditional-type)

Comment: This does not work for me because, if I return K directly, then the return type will always be `"Hello"|"Hi!"`, but I'm expecting it to be `"Hello"` when I pass "Hello" as a value (and a type) to `name` variable.