# "Conditional types" won't work with real function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm reading https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html

I'm wondering why this won't work?

```
interface IdLabel {
  id: number
}

interface NameLabel {
  name: string
}

type NameOrId<T extends number | string> = T extends number
  ? IdLabel
  : NameLabel;

function createLabel<T extends number | string>(idOrName: T): NameOrId<T> {
  if (typeof idOrName === 'number') {
    return { id: 1 }
  } else {
    return { name: 'foo' }
  }
}
```

However, this will work (which is the example given by the doc), but this is totally useless it even not returns any value...

```
function createLabel<T extends number | string>(idOrName: T): NameOrId<T> {
  throw "unimplemented";
}
```

Does the conditional types only works with "type definition"..?

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The short a answer is you can't. No value will be assignable to an unresolved conditional type (a conditional type that still depends on a free generic type variable). The only thing you can do is use a type assertion.

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52144866/12397250

So what you can do is:

#### 1. Type assertion

```js
function createLabel<T extends number | string>(idOrName: T): NameOrId<T> {
  if (typeof idOrName === 'number') {
    return { id: 1 } as NameOrId<T>
  } else {
    return { name: 'foo' } as NameOrId<T>
  }
}
```

#### 2. Overload the method

```js
function createLabel<T extends number | string>(idOrName: T): NameOrId<T>;
function createLabel(idOrName: number | string): IdLabel | NameLabel {
  if (typeof idOrName === 'number') {
    return { id: 1 }
  } else {
    return { name: 'foo' }
  }
}
```