# Confusion about generic return type based on input parameters

Tags: typescript

I'm going to present a couple of examples **with** and **without** generic return types and I'm confused as to why typescript doesn't treat all the examples the same.

Example 1: base case - function overload (works correctly)

```
function test(data:string):string
function test(data:string[]):string[]
function test(data:string | string[]): string | string[] {

  if(Array.isArray(data)){
     return ['']
  } 

  return data
}

const testArr = test([]) // return type is Array
const testStr=test('a') // return type is string
```

Now I'm gonna try to do the same with a `generic` data type:

Example 2: inferred return types from the function are wrong

```
function testGeneric<T extends string | string[]>(data:T){
  if(Array.isArray(data)){
     return ['']
  } 

  return data
}

const testArrGen = testGeneric([])
const testStrGen=testGeneric('a')
```

Example 3: The function itself has the return types wrong.

```
function testGeneric2<T extends string | string[]>(data:T): T extends string? T : T[]{
  if(Array.isArray(data)){
     return [''] // error
  } 

  return data // error
}

const testArrGen2 = testGeneric2([]) // string[] || never[]
const testStrGen2=testGeneric2('a') //  "a"| string[]
```

Now I would like to understand why examples **2** and **3** are wrong, and how could I create the correct implementation using generics.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFMA8EMFsAcA25QEYCwAoAZgVwHYDGALgJYD2+ox4AzsQBQAm0x0AXPQE6n4DmASk7Ee-LHiJlK1OoxZthovgG0AukO68Vq8QRIUqNes1YdN-UAB9Q57UJsitVh0rWgA3liyhQpbAwBBLi5oAE8AOlJaIJDQkzYBAU9MH1SucGJcLiplAHJcnRTQAF9QLyL0zOzQeWgsYvLCSnoZehjQAF5WxjUBUBBQcgBrLCb8FqNiAGURDsmGXOhcvoHh8oGoOCQUACZdSQNugHFwfHAeQgAeABUISBp8JloXJ2tbNQA+eI5rpO9ffwxMKRaLBMLfRLJVI+SpZHL5Qo+UrlGEZOE1Uz1RrNYjdGInKhdSYE86kQgMXr9MDvVRWaxnABu5zUoxx3RmXAJc1kJIuCyWKzAoAARNBhW9HPwWZgsBsYAhkKAAMz7fTSYmnUmEHY3O4PJ4vCwS1yqL61di-digW5QfXPWwAfmtoCt1zUUIBgTBESiQLitUh-zSaOqeQK-2RMoqIaotSxUbGE1k+NOO06x01Fx2FPUZUwidxkw5BJ23PovLJ2cWyyAA)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65986251/conditional-types-wont-work-with-real-function/65986342#65986342) answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

In example 2, no type information is declared for the result, no type inference is performed on the result.

The problem with Example 3 is that the returned array (`string []`) does not match the specified return type, which in case of an array type is `T[]` and `T` itself must not be of type string. It could have extended the string type. Furthermore the bound parameter type has to be used to let the parameter type `T` match the return type. You don't have to redeclare the type parameter `T` for the result.

I think this is how it should work:

```
function testGeneric2<T extends string | string[]>(data: T): T {
  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    const res: T = Object.create(data);

    return res;
  }

  return data;
}
```

Since no new object can be created from the type parameter out of the box (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382143/create-a-new-object-from-type-parameter-in-generic-class)), I created one from the array parameter using with Object.create.