# Unable to access property from conditional typing

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I want to have a function named `Control` that can be overloaded with props of two different types. This is the code I wrote. But it throws an error while trying to access specific properties of the prop.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
interface IControl {
    title: string,
    description: string,
    type: 'button' | 'switch'
}

type TButtonVariant = 'contained' | 'outlined' | undefined

interface IControlWithButton extends IControl {
    buttonText: string,
    buttonVariant: TButtonVariant
}

interface IControlWithSwitch extends IControl {
    isOn: boolean
}

type GetExactProp<T> = T extends { isOn: boolean } ? IControlWithSwitch : IControlWithButton;


function Control<T extends IControlWithButton | IControlWithSwitch>(props: GetExactProp<T>): void {
    console.log(props.buttonText) // Property 'buttonText' does not exist on type 'GetExactProp<T>'
    console.log(props.isOn) // Property 'isOn' does not exist on type 'GetExactProp<T>'
}

const ControlWithButtonProps: IControlWithButton = {
    title: 'Ola!',
    description: 'Section description',
    buttonText: 'I am a button',
    buttonVariant: 'contained',
    type: 'button'
}

const ControlWithSwitchProps: IControlWithSwitch = {
    title: 'Ola!',
    description: 'Section description',
    isOn: false,
    type: 'switch'
}

Control(ControlWithButtonProps)
Control(ControlWithSwitchProps)
```

*[Try this out in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGED24qYDbIDeAUMmcmMGHhAFzIDOYUoA5gDSnkAmEDCLAA6Vs9JixAcuZMAE9BdZAHIARgFcwYbEuQAfZQwDuVBAAslxAL7FichcgAqAIQ1aQANTgs44ZAF5lBGwwOFAIbh19JUwNPDCIvWQ1EF4YeJtQSFhEFAxg3DwAdSpTF01sZAgAD0gUhjQsHHwiaWR1cpAHarAxZjZOcjbXbE9vcHpnYY8vYB8wKwzwaHgkBvz8YrBTAGVjMDNKmog6taaCEkHgBgB5EHoVTHwIHwXbeRQAcQgwAFEqxDAAAVcIIADwOAB8-kch1q3HqhGQV1u90eNB8yEsyAA-KdmBsSrsTKZkPQ8mdNqUpgBuGzEGDJBAiEDIRr4vDg2HHeF4gqUspuRLk9mUon7UwQgAUghBDHoX1%20-yZwMwYMhAEp6AA3TDAbgtQZBEAMJ4AOjwmFY0tlpuRIHVyAA9I6KKZcIZ6tBcFB6CqFFA5Mo7TpuJg%20MgQJgwIcrtGKnYUEoFX8AX7wRCLNZiEamKz1kUSgLsH65byCVsiyyAhdyJRqIolNc8HAAIRKAY8PgCYDCYCiZTbCBMvss3j8ITM9utdpuLo1ehKVDIOAAW2XQw6U8GM5GMzmC6NIXiW9r7wXO5AmZsOejbL5hL2ZhLZLv5Z2j5J1dadZoC6brZPMgx27Xt%20yUQdhwqYCJxHQCkRuO5kHgPAGAgDsZDPAwPyvYhXzwSU8P5KYS3VXD8wI-NRQ-EigA)*

Comment: `props.type` return `button` Or `switch`

or

add `isOn` key in `interface IControl `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the error appears is:

> No value will be assignable to an unresolved conditional type (a conditional type that still depends on a free generic type variable)

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52144866/12397250

That's why Typescript has no idea what type `props` inside the function is. What you can do is to put a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) in the function, and the generic isn't really necessary here

```
function Control(props: IControlWithButton | IControlWithSwitch): void {
    if ("isOn" in props) {
        props; // IControlWithSwitch
        props.isOn; // boolean
        props.buttonText; // ERROR
    } else {
        props; // IControlWithButton
        props.isOn; // ERROR
        props.buttonText; // string
    }
}
```

Or create a [user defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
function isControlWithSwitch(control: IControlWithButton | IControlWithSwitch): control is IControlWithSwitch {
    return "isOn" in control;
}

function Control(props: IControlWithButton | IControlWithSwitch): void {
    if (isControlWithSwitch(props)) {
        props; // IControlWithSwitch
        props.isOn; // boolean
        props.buttonText; // ERROR
    } else {
        props; // IControlWithButton
        props.isOn; // ERROR
        props.buttonText; // string
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. Can we use `if ('isOn' of Object.keys(props))` equivalent to the second implementation?

Comment: Did you mean `if ('isOn' in Object.keys(props))`? As far as I know `Object.keys` can't be used as a type guard, since it returns an array of string (`string[]`).

Comment: Gotcha!
And I did mean `if ('isOn' of Object.keys(props))`. `in` will return the indices instead of the values.

Comment: I dont think `'isOn' of Object.keys(props)` is a correct JavaScript / TS syntax, `Object.keys(props)` will returns an array of string containing the keys of the object, so it will returns for example `["title", "description", "type", ...]`, and `in` is used to check whether a string of key exists in a object the one shown in my example. The closest thing I can think of is `if (Object.keys(props).includes("isOn"))`, which do similar thing with `in` but still doesn't support type guard. While `of` is used only in `for...of`