# Deep partial of a generic in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'd like to define a function that can return a *deep* partial of a generic type, but TS is reporting the problem shown below. Assuming my `DeepPartial` is defined correctly, I fail to see why `{}` should not be assignable to `DeepPartial<T>`.

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhFgAoEMBOwCWyA2AeAKgHxQC8U+UEAHsBAHYAmAzlABQZ0BmEqUAqgEoA2gF0oAfljwkaTDlx9CoqAC4oAbyhDEUDlADWEEAHtO5EeLVwEKdFjz5tI4gF8A3ACgPHWqk7IAY2g+Jh4NDyhIqDpkAFsINSZgVA4Ac08XL04AVzoAzGM6KE5jY1YBK2lbOTwQnmJ1CKjUCGBs1CL1dw9Mjxy8gqKAIzQCQnLKm1l7MfCoqBa2jo1ulyA)

```js
type DeepPartial<T> = T extends (infer U)[] ? DeepPartial<U>[] : { [P in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T[P]> };

interface User {
    name: string;
}

function foo(): DeepPartial<User> {
    return {}; // ok
}

function bar<T>(): DeepPartial<T> {
    return {}; // Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'DeepPartial<T>'.
}
```

NOTE: I get the same error even if `T` extends `object` or `Record<string, unknown>`.

Comment: Why don't you just use `type DeepPartial<T> = { [P in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T[P]> };`?  Why special-case arrays which get [mapped to arrays](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) anyway?

Comment: The answer to "why is `{}` not assignable to the original `DeepPartial<T>`?" is that the compiler cannot verify assignability to a conditional type depending on an as-yet unspecified generic type parameter; it simply *defers* evaluation of the generic.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52144772/simple-function-with-conditional-type) of which this might be considered a duplicate.

Comment: Of course, there's no way `{}` is assignable to an array anyway; if you call `bar<string[]>().map(x => x);` you get no compiler warning but a runtime error happens; the compiler can't really do much to help here, I'm afraid.  I'd be wary of anything that claims to be able to return a value of a type related to `T` without actually having a value of type `T` to start with.

Comment: @jcalz thanks, I didn't realize that behavior had changed. Defining `DeepPartial` without the conditional gets rid of the error, but as you said, it accepts `{}` when `T` might be an array.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that one difference with the simplified `type DeepPartial<T> = { [P in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T[P]> };` definition is that it makes all array _entries_ optional. In other words, it allows `[undefined]`.